Show keyboard layout name in the text box
On my laptop I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 (Unity). For my account I have configured 2 keyboard layouts (English and Ukrainian). Very often when I enter the text into the text box the keyboard layout (language) is not the one I expected. When that happens I have to clear the text and start from scratch. That is not a big deal but it is frustrating. I believe that is a quite common issue.
My question is there a way to display the keyboard layout name at the place where the cursor is so it is right at front of my eyes? For instance:
========================================
[en] hello worl_                      ||
========================================

or
========================================
[uk] hello worl_                      ||
========================================


isn't the language selected shown in the systray?

Having the keyboard layout switcher displayed constantly next to the mouse cursor would be super annoying indeed. I don't think there is an easy way.

@graham Yes, it is. But you do not usually look at that icon every time you're starting to write the text

@mikewhatever Not mouse cursor, but editor cursor like hello worl_[en] or at the beginning of the edit box like in the example above

surely it only takes a momentary glance at the systray if you are used to using different languages...
